# Android standalone apk installation problem

Tags: android, installation, apk

I am trying to install an application as a standalone apk (not in Android Market place) by placing the signed apk package on the SD card and then clicking it to install it.

The application installs fine and I start it however it will always crash unless the PC cable is connected to the phone in which case it works fine!

It is frustrating for me, I know it must be trying to save or access something on the PC or have a setting on the phone that needs changing.

I am sorry if this is a rather simple question, but I just do not know what I am doing wrong.

Any help with this would be much appreciated.

**EDIT (More Information):**

The application is a messaging application using a specific message protocol that has a background service that has a socket that listens for messages arriving and the application UI will listen to message events raised and also send messages by connecting to this service running.

The application does save details about the person who is logged in and the messages that have been received and uses GPS for navigation.

Specifically the application will always crash whenever the usb cable is NOT CONNECTED to the phone. I cannot get past the login screen which would start the background service and save the person who is logging in.

As for logcat output, well this is a release application and it works fine when I have been previously been debugging it from eclipse.

However now I am trying to create a release build to give to clients.

This is a snippet that I know will execute when I try and login however without the cable attached the application just crashes.

```
// Start the background connection to the server now the user is logged in
startService(new Intent(this, ConnectorBackgroundService.class));

// If there is a user that has been logged in otherwise load from settings
if (user == null) {
   user = loadUserFromSettings();
}

// Write the login to file to allow automatic login if the application is restarted
repository.saveLoggedInUser(user);
```

Comment: You have not provided information anyone could use to help you.  You need to explain what the application does, and post the logcat output from during the session where it crashes.

Comment: Chris is right, logcat is needed to see what's failing.  Since you can't see the logcat when the USB is disconnected without dumping, why not try to use the ADB wireless app?  This way, the USB won't be connected, and you'd still be able to see and retrieve the logcat in real-time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks anyone who spent time looking at this problem.

It was because I had an event which watched for the device being unplugged and plugged in because it stopped GPS the application was using when on battery to conserve battery.

As I was always testing the device when it was plugged in via USB, I never noticed that it was calling bad code when I unplugged the lead causing a null reference exception.

I guess I was always thinking that it was trying to communicate with the debugger or something which was why it was not working properly.

This site will finally allow me to put my own answer in.

Answer (score 0):

Have you removed dobug mode from manifest?

Comment: That would be no, that might be why!

Comment: Leaving debug mode active does not prevent independent running.